# How to change power status of Windows host from Ubuntu guest OS?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have an Ubuntu14.04 guest in VMWare Workstation 12 on Windows 7 host.

How can I change the power status of the host,e.g. power down or sleep,from the guest OS?

Answer (score 0):

Currently my way is use the share folder,in the guest OS:

```
echo "">/mnt/hgfs/share/sleep
```

Then on the host write a program to monitor whether the file "sleep" exist and execute sleep action.

For power down,the program monitor vmware-vmx.exe,when it disappears,it shutdown the computer.

The C# program is like:

```
 class ShutdownComputer
{
    //true for sleep,false for shutdown
    static bool sleep = true;
    static public void ShutdownComputerDo()
    {
        string[] process_names = new string[]
        {
            "vmware-vmx",
        };

        while (true)
        {
            bool done = true;
            string sleep_signal_fn = @"C:\VMachine\VM_Ubuntu14.04\share\sleep";
            if (sleep)
            {
                done = File.Exists(sleep_signal_fn);
                if (done) File.Delete(sleep_signal_fn);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (string pn in process_names)
                {
                    if (Process.GetProcessesByName(pn).Length > 0) done = false;
                }
            }



            if (done)
            {
                var psi=sleep?
                new ProcessStartInfo("rundll32.exe", " powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0")
                : new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
                psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                Process.Start(psi);

                if (!sleep) break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Although it works,are there any easier ways?